# Matrix multiplication Error: non-conformable arguments. Im wondering why I get this error while trying to solve c%*%b if b%*c works

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

```
> b
       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    7    4
 [2,]    1    2

> c
 [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    3    8    1
 [2,]    2    0    4

> b%*%c
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
     [1,]   29   56   23
     [2,]    7    8    9
  
> c%*%b
Error in c %*% b : non-conformable arguments
```

I am just trying to do simple matrix multiplication for my linear algebra class. I understand how to do it by hand but for some reason, I get an error when trying to multiply c%*%b even though b%*% works

Comment: As noted in the answers, you must have *conformable* matrices in order to multiply them.  Also note that `c()` is a commonly used R function and naming object `c` is generally confusing / bad practice.  Maybe go with `mat_b` and `mat_c` instead :)

Comment: (a nice tool: http://matrixmultiplication.xyz/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix `c` is of size `2x3`, while `b` is of `2x2`.

I am not sure if you want `t(c) %*% b`, where `t()` is matrix transpose.

Comment: I know the dimensions are different but how come b%*%c worked but not c%*%b

Comment: @AnthonyChey I think you'd better read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication regarding matrix multiplication

Comment: Ok yeah i just realized its not a coding error but a multiplication rule with matrices. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

An option is also to use `crossprod`

```
crossprod(c, b)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   23   16
#[2,]   56   32
#[3,]   11   12
```